# Crashlytics support for macOS

Tags: macos, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have a few queries on Crashlytics for Mac OS X.

1. Are both Crashlytics and Answers free or do we need a licence for their use? Does it require some licence after it reaches a certain number of maximum users?
2. From https://get.fabric.io/roadmap , it seems Crashlytics will be integrated with Firebase. From the same page I can see that Firebase supports only iOS and Android apps. So, what will happen to Mac OS X support? Can we continue using the Fabric dashboard or will there be a Mac OS X dashboard in Firebase after the migration? Basically our concern is whether the support for Mac OS X will be continued in future or dropped.

Comment: Looks like it will be dropped. Any suggestions for a Crashlytics replacement for macOS apps?

Comment: Backtrace could be a good replacement on macOS: https://backtrace.io/for/macos/

Answer (score 0):

1. According to their [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) Crashlytics and Analytics are free.
2. Firebase Crashlytics [gained support for macOS last year](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2149#issuecomment-537113289).